# error while trying to tokenizing a string and insert each part in an array

Tags: c, tokenize

```
while (fgets(buff, sizeof (char*)*100, file)) {
    if (line == 0) {
        fgets(buff, sizeof (char*)*100, file);
        line++;
    }

    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok(buff, ",");
    char *array[10];

    while (p != NULL) {
        array[i++] = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    if (!strcmp(array[1], "03/04/2020")) {
        *inf += atof(array[i - 2]);
        *dead += atof(array[i - 1]);
        *rec += atof(array[i]);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to split the line which has the following format:

```
3245,03/04/2020,Jiangxi,Mainland China,2020-03-04T01:33:07,935.0,1.0,884.0
```

i tried using `strtok` with `","` delimiter but I kept getting this `

> RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,819, total time: 1s

If my  code is not clear PLEASE DO NOT HESITATE TO ASK ME ABOUT IT

Comment: Post a [mcve].  As is, others can not successfully compile the posted code.

Comment: `-1,073,741,819` is what you get when you print the `DWORD` `3,221,225,477` as a signed integer. `3,221,225,477`  aka `0xC0000005` is what Windows uses to signal a Protection Fault ("SIGSEGV" in unix parlance). It means you are dereferencing a pointer variable that contains `NULL` or some other bad value.

Comment: Make sure `i >= 2` after the loop, otherwise `array[i-2]` will access outside the array.

Comment: Errors will happen if there's a blank line in the file, since there won't be any tokens.

Comment: Instead of `if (line == 0)` test every time through the loop, skip the heading line by calling `fgets()` once before the loop.

Comment: `sizeof(char *)*100` seems wrong in this context.  Presumably your array is a character array, not an array of character pointers.

Comment: Please post the contents of (say) the first 4 lines of the input file, including any blank lines, etc

Comment: @TomKarzes i guess its correct, since im considering the whole line as a string and then tokenizing it into array[].

Comment: @user362949 the file does not contain any blank lines. It has the same format as the line i posted.

Comment: @omar Your guess is incorrect.  You're storing characters directly into that array, not pointers.

Comment: which array do u mean ? buff or array [] ? @TomKarzes

Comment: @omar I'm talking about `buff`.  Look at this call:  `fgets(buff, sizeof (char*)*100, file)`.  You need to pass a character count, which should be `sizeof(char)*nelements`.  Instead you're using `sizeof(char *)*100` which makes no sense. This says you're reading characters into a buffer large enough to hold 100 character *pointers*, not characters.

Comment: oh okay i understand. thank you for your help @TomKarzes

Comment: @omar No problem :)

Comment: @omar By the way, in the case of `fgets`, you're really just passing a character count, so you can just do `fgets(buff, nelements, file)`.  You don't need the `sizeof` there (although `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1).

Comment: yeah thats right, thanks :D @TomKarzes

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a blank line in the file. It won't have any tokens, so `i` will be `0` after the loop. `array[i]` will be uninitialized, and `array[i-1]` and `array[i-2]` will be outside the array, so accessing them causes undefined behavior.

Check that you've gotten enough tokens, and skip the line otherwise.

Also, since you increment `i` after assigning the token, `array[i]` is after the elements that you assigned. You should be using `i-3`, `i-2`, and `i-1` to get the last 3 tokens.

```
// skip header line
fgets(buff, sizeof (char*)*100, file);

while (fgets(buff, sizeof (char*)*100, file)) {
    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok(buff, ",");
    char *array[10];

    while (p != NULL) {
        array[i++] = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    if (i <= 3) { // skip lines that don't have enough tokens
        continue;
    }
    if (!strcmp(array[1], "03/04/2020")) {
        *inf += atof(array[i - 3]);
        *dead += atof(array[i - 2]);
        *rec += atof(array[i-1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is i cannot skip any line because i need to extract the last three numbers from each line. Also, im sure that the file does not contain blank lines :(

Comment: There may be a blank line at the end.

Comment: and by the way, some lines may miss some elements such as : 3245,03/04/2020,,Mainland China,2020-03-04T01:33:07,935.0,1.0,884.0

Comment: true, i just checked and found that theres a blank line at the end. what would you suggest doing to fix this ?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem since you don't use the empty fields. `strtok()` will store those as empty tokens.

Comment: My answer should handle that fine. It will just ignore the last line.

Comment: it didnt work for some reason. inf,dead, rec remained equal to 0.

Comment: I can't help any more now. Use a debugger or add `printf()` statements to see what's happening.